# Using Picasso to get Images from Gallery

Tags: android, file, android-alertdialog, picasso

I'm using Picasso to get images from the gallery. I've followed a few Questions around the same topic on SO but haven't seemed to have fixed my issue. I got my file path from onActivityResult and tried adding the "file:" + .... + ".jpg" to the file and setting it to the ImageView. But it doesn't seem to be setting to it.

```
public class PictureDialog extends DialogFragment {
private ImageView imageView;
private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
private Button saveMemory;
private Bitmap bitmap, bMapScaled;
private FinishedMemorySaving fMS;

public interface FinishedMemorySaving {
    void showMemory(Memory memory);
}

public PictureDialog(){

}

public static PictureDialog newInstance(Memory memory){
    PictureDialog pictureDialog = new PictureDialog();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", memory.getTitleMem());
    args.putString("desc", memory.getDescMem());
    args.putDouble("lat", memory.getLocationMem().latitude);
    args.putDouble("lng", memory.getLocationMem().longitude);
    args.putString("date", memory.getFormatedDate());
    pictureDialog.setArguments(args);

    return pictureDialog;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    // request a window without the title
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    return dialog;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.picture_dialog, container);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    final String title = getArguments().getString("title");
    final String desc = getArguments().getString("desc");
    final double lat = getArguments().getDouble("lat");
    final double lng = getArguments().getDouble("lng");

    imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.memPic);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        }
    });

    saveMemory = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.saveMemory);
    saveMemory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Memory memory = new Memory();
            memory.setTitleMem(title);
            memory.setDescMem(desc);
            memory.setLocationMem(new LatLng(lat, lng));
            memory.setFormatedDate(new Date());
            memory.setImageMem(bitmap);

            try {
                saveToCloud(memory);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null){
        String path = data.getData().getPath();
        File file = new File("file:" + String.valueOf(path) + ".jpg");
        Log.i("FILE ERROR", "file:" + path + ".jpg");
        setPicImage(file);
        //imageView.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled);
    }

}

public void setPicImage(File file){
    if(file == null){
        Log.i("FILE ERROR", "No file " + file.getPath());
    } else {
      // WHERE I WANT TO SET THE IMAGE TO FROM PICASSO
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(file).centerInside().fit().into(imageView);
    }
}

.........    

}
```

I get this when I print out the File Path when I added the "file:" etc:

> file:/external/images/media/6854.jpg

Just hoping to find something that might help me set it to the ImageView. Thanks.